# Prevent ACRA from sending duplicate exception

Tags: android, acra, acralyzer

I'm using **ACRA**, to sending crash reports to my server. But for two reason, I don't want to send duplicate exceptions to server:

1. It's boring and make it hard to read and handle exceptions in panel.
2. My server bandwidth is limited.

So is there any option to **enable/disable** sending duplicate exceptions?

Duplicate exceptions means duplicate exceptions in specific device. For example if there is a button in my application that cause of a error, I don't want to send occurred error each time user push that button.(If application version increased, it should be sent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this OOTB.

To do so would mean that you would need to build a database of crashes on your device and check to see if *that* error had occurred previously.

ACRA is designed to be lightweight and robust. Added that kind of functionality into it would diminish both of those design criteria.

I suggess you consider using a commercial cloud instance for your crash reporting instead of relying on your own server. A good crash server will aggregate crash instances for you. Which let's you focus on the high volume ones.

Comment: if 1 million people installed my application in their devices, and all of them at same time get a exception, there is 1M request to my/commercial server. What will happen?! Server overload?! Server down!? DDos Attack?! How can i handle this situation?

Comment: 1) Use expandable cloud capability. 2) Design and test your software to a higher degree. If you have 1 million stalls then you ought to be generating enough money to afford it.